# Add custom OData 'built in' methods to ODataServer endpoint

Tags: odata

OData has it's own built in methods, like 'contains' 'endswith' 'geo.intersects' and so on..

Is there a way to add my own custom method? So I could give it a name, parameters and the Expression I want it to be translated to.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C#, you can go with your custom methods with [WebGet] annotation and IQueryable as the result. Then you need to register them by SetServiceOperationRule on DataServiceConfiguration. After that you can go with api/service.svc/YourMethodName. Hope it helps.